# Extract specific label value in Prometheus and set this as query result value

Tags: prometheus

I have a query which return resultant value in Prometheus output query and in value it return 1.
I tried to google a bit but unfortunately didn't succeed in getting the required answer.

My use case is as below.

I executed following query => hrMemorySize{job="snmp-moxa"} in prometheus query browser

it give me following result ->
Element
hrMemorySize{hrMemorySize="125072",instance="1.1.1.1",job="snmp-moxa"}
value 1

my requirement is to get this hrMemorySize in value or is there any way I can parse this and set output into this hrMemorySize as value.

I know in grafana we can use label_values but I am not using grafana for visualization instead we have custom build application which is using these queries.

Comment: What gives you that metric? A custom exporter? Is it something you can change? This may come a little rough, but putting a value into a label is just beyond anti-pattern. The best way to get the value in this case is to save the value as a value and not as a label. Read the "Caution" section here https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/#labels for the reason why.

Comment: Well the metrics gives above value {hrMemorySize{hrMemorySize="125072",instance="1.1.1.1",job="snmp-moxa"}} for the exporter part I have a snmp / mib file which intern generates all the metrics based on  the mib (oid: 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.2
      type: Integer32). So I can't have much space for the custom exporter.

Answer (score 1):

Currently prometheus metrics types include counter, gauge, histogram, and summary. They are all numeric types.

But Prometheus labels are always Strings, so I think should be no functions to transform metric labels to metric values.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus doesn't provide functionality for converting label value to time series value. If you really need this functionality, then take a look at [label_value()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_value) function provided by VictoriaMetrics - this is a Prometheus-like monitoring solution I work on.

**Important note**: it isn't recommended using Prometheus labels for storing potentially unbound number of unique values such as `hrMemorySize` in the label above, since this may lead to [high cardinality issues](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/FAQ.html#what-is-high-cardinality) because every unique label value generates new [time series](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#time-series). It is much better to store the `hrMemorySize` label value as the metric value itself, e.g. `hrMemorySize{instance="1.1.1.1",job="snmp-moxa"} 125072`